# How do the following fulltext search within mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to search the keywords "love" on fulltext index mode? Or is this situation  suitable for fulltext search mode?  Any  reply will be appreciated.

For example

- A column contains the below words with the stop word "_":
- "I_love_you",
- "He_is_cute",

..

Comment: i'm quite sure what you mean. but is `SELECT t.* FROM table t WHERE text_field LIKE '%love%'` should enough to search the keyword _love_ in your table

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the like mode is a disaster when the records  are large.

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL has supported FULLTEXT indexes since version 3.23.23. VARCHAR
>   and TEXT Columns that have been indexed with FULLTEXT can be used with
>   special SQL statements that perform the full text search in MySQL.

Here's how you might add a FULLTEXT index to some table columns.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT(column_name);
```

You can also add for multiple columns.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT(column_name,column_name,column_name);
```

Once you have a FULLTEXT index, you can search it using MATCH and AGAINST statements. For example:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name 
WHERE MATCH (column_name) AGAINST ('Love');

SELECT column_name,column_name FROM table_name 
WHERE MATCH (column_name,column_name) AGAINST ('Love');
```

Comment: Thanks. But this way can not work well. The result is always empty.